# How to delete last column in csv?

Tags: notepad++

Kept trying various options through regex 
(^([^ ]*).*, etc), but wasn't successful.

I have a comma separated file, and would like to delete the last column.

thanks

Comment: If you can share what exactly you have tried, then someone from community would be able to spot the error and help you

Comment: Actually, I used the same which was suggested below [^,]*$, however, it only deletes the first row's last column. The issue could be that the data in the last column is long and sometimes doe snot even finish properly instead of     }"   , just abruptly ends. I wonder if there is a way to tall for example to delete everything after the first     "     ?

Answer (score -1):

A regex solution is:

```
,[^,]*$
```

Does not work for csv files with comma's between quotes in the column.

Comment: `lookahead` and `lookbehind` have specific meanings in regexes which don't apply to yours. It's really just looking for a comma followed by 0 or more non-commas at the end of the line. However, that doesn't work for csv's with quoted fields, for example think about what it does on `column0,"column, the first"`.

Comment: and I do have those....in the last column which should be deleted. The before columns do not have quotes.